# Center a li inside a component using scrollIntoView() (VUE.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component with several li in them and when I click one of them I would like the clicked li centered itself inside the component so as to see it in the center of the view.

```
      <card-maintenance
        v-for="manutenzione in manutenzioni"
        :key="manutenzione.id"
        :name="manutenzione.nome"
        :data="manutenzione.data"
        :durata="manutenzione.durata"
        :desc="manutenzione.desc"
        :responsabile="manutenzione.responsabile"
        :machineType="manutenzione.machineType"
        :machineSubType="manutenzione.machineSubType"
    
     
        @click="centerItem(idex)"
      >
        
      </card-maintenance>
```

```
   centerItem(index){
    getElementById(index).scrollIntoView({
      block: "center"
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <card-maintenance
    v-for="manutenzione in manutenzioni"
    :key="manutenzione.id"
    :name="manutenzione.nome"
    :data="manutenzione.data"
    :durata="manutenzione.durata"
    :desc="manutenzione.desc"
    :responsabile="manutenzione.responsabile"
    :machineType="manutenzione.machineType"
    :machineSubType="manutenzione.machineSubType"
    :id="manutenzione.id"
    @click="centerItem(manutenzione.id)"
  >
  </card-maintenance>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).